# No color while rendering smoke

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I'm just starting Blender and I have a problem with rendering smoke. I'm using blender 2.8. So while being in solid mode I can see animated colors, but once I switch to rendered mode it becomes grey.

As a test I've started a new project and got the same result. I used Quick effects to get smoke.

What should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show an image of the materials for the smoke domain.

Answer (score 3):

You need to type "color" in the Color Attribute box in the domain shader.[image: example]